# How to find the start and end index of a word based on a given index within the word?

Tags: c#, string

For example, if there was a TextBox that contained this text:

`The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.`

And the blinking cursor (text caret) of the textbox was located at the `i` in `quick`, what would be an elegant way of finding the index for the `q` and the index for the `k`?

Basically, given a position in the string, how would I find the index of the beginning and end of the word? If the given index is a space assume it uses the previous word.

I have a really hackish solution using loops going in both direction until each finds a space but it's really messy and I was wondering if there was a more simplistic way to approach the problem. It's late so I feel like I may be missing something obvious here.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Perhaps post your code on [Code Review SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using loops in both directions sounds like the right approach to me - but *you* don't need to write the loops. You can use `String.IndexOf` and `String.LastIndexOf`:

```
int nextSpace = text.IndexOf(' ', index);
int previousSpace = text.LastIndexOf(' ', index);
```

It *will* be fiddly, and you should also consider that words don't always break at space boundaries - but that should at least get rid of your loops :)